# Unable to select the value in the drop down in selenium Web Driver for the website Goibibo

Tags: java, selenium, drop-down-menu

This is the code which I am using. I want to select different values from the "class" drop down. I am getting the count of the no. of drop downs as correct but the values are not getting selected under the dropdown.

```
    package selectclasspackage;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.junit.Test;
    //import org.junit.Before;
    import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

    import java.util.List;

    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

    public class selectclass {

        @Test
        public void Sample () throws InterruptedException {
             System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\Users\\Rajiv\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
             WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver ();

             String URL = "https://www.goibibo.com/";
             driver.get(URL);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Thread.sleep(3000);


            Select seatingclass = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("gi_class")));
            List <WebElement> elementCount = seatingclass.getOptions();
            System.out.println(elementCount.size());

            seatingclass.selectByVisibleText ("Premium Economy");
            System.out.println("Premium Economy selected");
            Thread.sleep(3000);


            for (int i = 0; i < elementCount.size(); i++)
            {
               new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("gi_class"))).selectByIndex(i);
            }


            seatingclass.selectByIndex(2);
            System.out.println("First Class selected");
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            seatingclass.selectByValue("B");
            System.out.println("Business Class selected");
            Thread.sleep(3000);

                }
        }
```

Comment: So is it selecting or not? And why are selecting it inside a loop?

Comment: which option do you want to select?

Comment: just remove the for loop and choose whatever you want

Comment: @Madhan It's not selecting the value. It is giving the count of values inside the dropdown as 4 which is correct. But after that when i want to select the different values using select by value,select by index,select by visible text I am unable to do so.

Comment: @Kushal Any option from the class drop down is fine but I am unable to. I tried removing the for loop also but no luck.

Comment: but for me it is able to select Business class option perfectly

Comment: using the same code ? @kushal

Comment: When I am running the code on left hand side of the Web page i am seeing the error as "Error:Please enter a valid Source". I am not able to figure where am I making error.

Comment: You are instantiating new instances of the select webelelement inside the loop but never assigning them to anything, so they exist long enough to select the option, then -poof- they're gone.   You probably wouldn't even notice them happening.  Change it to seatingclass and add a 2-3 second sleep inside that loop if you want to see the results.

Comment: @RajivPahuja: first remove select from the for loop

Comment: Were you able to observe the behavior? Was it properly selecting the items?  Or was there no difference?

Comment: I made some changes in the code below. First I change the URL because that webpage was throwing some error Secondly @BillHileman in for loop i changed the select loop to seating class and added wait time for viewing the output. But Still it is not working.

Comment: @BillHileman I was not able to observe any diffrence only the count of no of elements in dropdown got changed but the values weren't getting highlighted.

Comment: @kushal. i removed select from the for loop. but still no effect.

Comment: @RajivPahuja which value do you want to select?

Comment: @kushal. I am just a newbie in Selenium . I am just practising so any value selection is fine for me.

Comment: Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `for` loop? `selectByValue` works fine as the number of options in `#selnoOfAdults` are fixed. The below code worked fine. It selected 10 in the `#selnoOfAdults`.

```
Select seatingclass = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selnoOfAdults")));
seatingclass.selectByValue("10");
```

Comment: Tried removing the for loop also no effect.

Select seatingclass = new Select (driver.findElement(By.id("selnoOfAdults")));

seatingclass.selectByValue("5");
Thread.sleep(10000);